# Flutter: Use choice function with PopupMenuButton to navigate to another page

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to navigate back to the login page from a 'Sign Out' button on a PopupMenuButton list located on the app's homepage. The SignOut button I'm trying to configure looks like this:

[image]

The simplified code looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Home Page'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        PopupMenuButton<String>(
          onSelected: choiceAction,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return MenuOptions.choices.map((String choice){
              return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: choice,
                child: Text(choice),
              );
            }).toList();
```

and  `onSelected` calls the following `choiceAction`:

```
  void choiceAction(String choice) {
    setState() {
      if (choice == MenuOptions.SignOut) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem I'm facing is that it says `context` in Navigator.push is undefined. I'm not sure if I use the context defined in `Widget build(BuildContext context)` or `itemBuilder: (BuildContext context)` and I am lost on how I would fix the error that its undefined to make it use the definition where its being called in `onSelected`.

Comment: You can pass the context: `onSelected: () => choiceAction(context)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to send context to your function too. The only thing that you need to do is like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text('Home Page'),
  actions: <Widget>[
    PopupMenuButton<String>(
      onSelected: (choice) => choiceAction(choice, context),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return MenuOptions.choices.map((String choice){
          return PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: choice,
            child: Text(choice),
          );
        }).toList();
```

and your choice action function should be like this:

```
void choiceAction(String choice, BuildContext context) {
setState() {
  if (choice == MenuOptions.SignOut) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
    );
    }
  }
}
```